# Sequelize Association with alias "addresses" does not exist on User

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I was doing a tutorial with node, MySQL and Sequelize everything was going well but there came a point where I can't get out of this error: "Error: Association with alias" addresses "does not exist on User" has anyone been there?
Follow my code: https://github.com/Akssasori/sequelize2. I searched the stack and tried several things but it seems that my User.associate (connection.models); is not recognized

I always get this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Association with alias "addresses" does not exist on User
```

but I added User.associate (connection.models); on my model

Comment: Show a Sequelize request causes this error

Comment: when I send a get to that route "http://localhost:3333/users/1/addresses" should list the association by id

Comment: Can you look at `User.associations` just before the line with `await User.findByPk`?

Comment: I believe that not because I first look for the user id to find the associated address there, I must first search for the userId

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. You created separate Sequelize connections for User and Address models that's why they don't know about each other associations.
   Remove connection creation from both model modules along with `checkcon` call.
2. You shouldn't initialize a model inside model modules. There are enough those `init` calls in `database.js` because you need a single Sequelize connection instance to initialize them (created in `database.js`).
3. You should import `database.js` somewhere while starting a server in order to create  a Sequelize connection and register models and their associations.
   For test's simplicity you can just import it in `server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const routes = require(__dirname +'/routes');
// the below line was added
require(__dirname +'/database')
```

Comment: I 'll try do this now